# Spring Boot and Mongo DB: only get latest version of Document

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a document collection where each unique templateId can have multiple versions:

```
@Document(collection = "templates")
public class TemplateEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String templateId;
    private int version;
}
```

**Is there an easy way to only get the latest versions for each templateId with a simple MongoRepository interface method?**

Here is my current programmatic workaround to explain what I am trying to do and my helper query method to sort the list for my needs:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public List<TemplateEntity> listTemplates() {
    List<TemplateEntity> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    List<TemplateEntity> allTemplates = repository.findAllByOrderByTemplateIdAscVersionDesc();
    String templateId = "";
    for (TemplateEntity tpl : allTemplates) {
        if (!tpl.getTemplateId().equals(templateId)) {
            filtered.add(tpl);
            templateId = tpl.getTemplateId();
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Why wont you add sort and limit 
    List<TemplateEntity> allTemplates = repository.findAllByOrderByTemplateIdAscVersionDescLimit(int limit);

Comment: @Vipul Hm, I didn't find any documentation regarding this (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html). Only Top and First, but this is limiting the results and is not what I want. Limit seems to be the same thing or where do you have this from?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of operation you need to make use of the [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

```
db.getCollection("templates").aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": "$templateId", "tmpId": { "$first": "$_id" }, "maxVersion": { "$max": "$version"} } },
    { "$project": {"_id": "$tmpId", "templateId": "$_id", "version": "$maxVersion"} }
])
```

Spring Data offers support for Aggregations via `MongoOperations`. Please have a look at the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).

Generally speaking I think having something like an `@Aggregate` annotation in Spring Data would be benefitial. I've opended [DATAMONGO-2153](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2153) to investigate that option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Had a look into aggregation as well, but it seems in the $group part I have to add all fields I need to have in the result. Or is there a way the actual document is returned?